# If you dont apply the image to an object does parse.com still charge you for storage?

Tags: image, parse-platform

I have to work with some rather large images and multiples of them. During my testing I test uploaded several which I didnt apply to an actual object. Now It says I have taken up .7% of my 20 gigs with only 3 images on an object.

Does parse keep all images I uploaded previously even though I never applied them to an object? Is there a way to clear this data out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it still counts against your storage, because the file is still there even if you haven't saved a reference to it on a ParseObject.  You can clear out files that have not been assigned to Parse Objects by going into the Settings page and scrolling down to "Clean Up Files".

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your answer! I wish they would give some kind of indicator when you reach a certain % of unused files.